# Which statistical method should I use for this skewed data?

Tags: statistics

I have 334 data peaks from an astronomy project which were recorded at times over several years. At each time point I look at the position on the celestial sphere directly above my location. 48 of the data points are closely located together between o and 18 arc seconds apart (my arbitrary threshold for close). Due to the latitude of my position and rotation of the earth, the vertical direction above me follows a circle with the north pole at its centre. This circle could be called my zenith orbit and is approximately un-changing.  I have plotted the ordered time differences between all the data points as they appear on the zenith orbit in the histogram below.

[image]

The data point positions can only fall on the zenith orbit which is a fixed diameter. If I add more data the data points will be closer together  and probability that they will coincide will increase.

Which is the most appropriate statistical method, that will allow for the skewed data, to calculate whether the data points coincide by accident or could be genuinely co-located?

Comment: It is unclear what is your original data set. Do you have a vector of time points and a vector of locations where each time point were recorder, and you are interested in association between the two?

Comment: @V. Vancak  My original data set is date and time. I obtained close data points by subtracting all date-times from the first date then doing modulo division with the value of a sidereal day in seconds as the divisor. Data points with similar quotients will be closely located on the celestial sphere. The values in my histogram are actually the excel code for the number of seconds as a fraction of a day. I want  some indication whether  the close data points occurred by chance.

Comment: I think you would get more help if you clarify exactly how a point is added, what data has each point and any bias you think may have affected the process. Because I, and I assume many others, am not familiar enough with astronomy to understand your question.

Comment: @ ACheca Thanks for your comment, I have edited my question to make it clearer, hopefully